# mysql event runs but doesnt execute the query

Tags: mysql, events

I used to have an archiving event that used to run once everyday without a problem but then recently when I checked, I found out that my event still runs but the query wasn't executed. So I dropped the old event and recreated it and only changed the name and the execution time but now it says there's something wrong with the syntax when I use a mysql syntax checker but it runs using php the only problem is it executes the 2nd query which is delete instead of the 1st first query which is insert. The event looks like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`ricoj`@`%` EVENT `log_archiving` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS 
'2016-06-29 12:00:00' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE DO BEGIN
insert into archives
select * from app_log where date_sub(curdate( ) , interval 75 DAY) >=  created_datetime;
delete from app_log where date_sub(curdate( ) , interval 75 DAY) >=  created_datetime;
END
```

Comment: do you get any error message from mysql? Have you tried to execute the query directly? Maybe your user does not have delete right?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Comment: The syntax issue was solved by adding a delimiter. Im still not sure thou why my old event's query stopped working even if the event was executed.